# What's the technique for altering clichés?

Tags: terminology

Is there a specific word for when you take well known sayings and you switch some of the words like if I changed "he had a heart of stone" to "he had a heart of wood". I know anastrophe means you change the order of a saying but is there a word when you actually change the content of a saying slightly such that it is still recognisable?

Comment: Are you looking for a formal term or would a simple “*play* on a well-known saying” suffice?  Or even more informal ***riff***.

Comment: @Jim I'm looking for a formal term that I can use in an essay

Comment: What kind of essay?  An English language writing assignment or some academic/scholarly essay?  Just cuz you’re going to turn it in doesn’t mean it can’t contain everyday speech.  In fact some essays depend on it.

Comment: @Jim Some high-school analytical essay on the poetry of Yeats, I need something really specific that I can use cos high school teachers really want you to use a formal term whenever you analyse something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s called *metalepsis*.

> Metalepsis (from Greek: μετάληψις) is a figure of speech in which a word or a phrase from figurative speech is used in a new context.
> [-wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalepsis)

They give the following example as a metalepsis of “the early bird catches the worm”.

> I've got to catch the worm tomorrow.